# What is the correct way to add an Android Library to an Android Project?

Tags: android, eclipse, dependencies, libraries, android-appcompat

I am trying to add `android-support-v7-appcompat` to my newly created Android project.

Following the Support Library Setup Documentation (developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html), section **Adding libraries with resources**, I have created an android-support-v7-appcompat project, before adding it as an Android dependency.

EDIT: Here are more details on the process I followed to add the library project as an Android Dependency to the main project:

1. In the Project Explorer, right-click your project and select Properties.
2. In the category panel on the left side of the dialog, select Android.
3. In the Library pane, click the Add button.
4. Select the library project and click OK.

However, even if the dependency is correctly recognized, Eclipse still sees the compatibility references, such as `ActionBarActivity`, as errors, forbidding me to build the project. [(See picture here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRyOl.png).

To solve this problem, I tried the solutions accepted by similar questions on SE, i.e. adding android-support-v7-appcompat to the Project's Build Path, which successfully silents the errors that prevented me to compile earlier.

However, now when building and deploying the project, I get an error: the app crashes at launch, and the Console displays an error message: `Could not find android-support-v7-appcompat.apk!` [(See picture here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hT6w.png).

To resume, with the **first configuration** I am not able to compile with Eclipse, while with the **second configuration** I can't launch the application.

Therefore, I have two questions:

- First, how should I be adding a library to my project, so I can at the same time build my project **and** be able to use the library's additions in my code in Eclipse?
- Secondly, I feel like I am missing theoretical knowledge on how Eclipse handles dependencies.
  What is the difference between adding a library as Android dependency vs Java Dependency / vs adding the project or its jar to the Build path?

Comment: You still need to add the support library. Right-click on Project/Android/Add Support Library

Comment: @323go: Thank you for your comment, but I already did so, and didn't notice any change. Should I restart Eclipse or something afterwards?

Comment: "before adding it as an Android dependency" -- you have not explained how you did this. "adding android-support-v7-appcompat to the Project's Build Path" -- that is not the correct solution. Never manually modify your Eclipse build path. "how should I be adding a library to my project" -- the same way you do any library project, by importing the library into your Eclipse workspace, then attaching it to the app project via Project > Properties > Android.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I edited my question to explain the process I followed.

As the Support Library Setup Documentation advises, I imported the library as a project in my workspace, before attaching it in Project via Properties > Android just as you advise: It is the **second configuration** I described, where I get the `Could not find android-support-v7-appcompat.apk` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First, how should I be adding a library to my project, so I can at the same time build my project and be able to use the library's additions in my code in Eclipse?

Your first approach should be fine, which would indicate that there is some other problem. For example, there may be errors in the `appcompat` library project that are preventing it from being compiled. However, given the error from the second approach, either you are running the `appcompat` library (which will not work) or something else is more fundamentally broken in your project setup, where your app thinks that it is supposed to build `android-support-v7-appcompat.apk`, when there is no such APK.

> What is the difference between adding a library as Android dependency vs Java Dependency / vs adding the project or its jar to the Build path?

Never manually modify the build path in Eclipse for an Android project. While that will satisfy the compiler, the contents of the JAR(s) will not be packaged into your APK for use at runtime, resulting in runtime crashes (e.g., `VerifyError`).

"Java dependency" is for pure Java source code. Not only do you not have the source code to `appcompat` from the SDK, but an Android library project includes Android resources (and, at least on Android Studio, also assets and an optional manifest file).

For Eclipse, library projects are attached via the approach you describe as the first approach in your question. For Eclipse, plain JARs are just dropped into `libs/` in your project root, and those are automatically added to your compile-time and runtime classpaths.

Comment: Thank you for the useful theoretical clarification. 

However, this conforts me in believing that problems arise despite me doing the right thing: I created a new project, imported the compat lib, referenced it under Project > Properties > Android, and am still facing the Eclipse errors.

When you say "**never manually modify the build path**", does this include Eclipse's "Fix project setup..." quick solution? And if yes, then what can I do to solve this by myself?

Comment: @PLNech: "does this include Eclipse's "Fix project setup..." quick solution?" -- no, because AFAIK that does not manually modify the build path either. "what can I do to solve this by myself?" -- I'd start by examining the imported `appcompat` in Eclipse and see if there are any error markers. For example, it might be requiring a version of the SDK Platform that you have not downloaded from the SDK Manager.

Comment: As far as I can see, Eclipse's solutions here are `Add project to build path` and `Add archive to build path`, thus modifying it.

I will investigate further the correctness of the downloaded library and the completeness of my Eclipse installation.

Comment: After restarting from scratch and downloading again `appcompat`, the import went well. I am still not sure where was the problem, but it is now solved. Thank you!